# is there any Pyloris-like for Tornado?

Tags: tornado, ddos

My question seems to be dumb, but found [this page](http://hackforlulz.blogspot.com/p/tools.html) and he mentioned some tools to make dDos attacks, i want to test my application how many concurent connections can handle, but this tools seems  to be for thread-based webserver architecture?

How do i test my application made on Tornado (Event driven)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use siege, although I've never used it with tornado so I can't speak to that.  Here's a link to how to install and use it: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/test-your-web-server-lay-siege-to-it/5171727

Comment: sadly it is not supported on Windows, here is the link http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/

Comment: here is the result, what do you think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034018/what-about-the-c10k-in-practice