# What about the C10k in practice?

Tags: tornado, c10k

I just tested a small application made using *Tornado*, and i'm far from the *10k simultanuous connections*!
To make the test, i've used [Siege](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/), under **OpenSuse 12.2 64 bit**, the machine is **i7** with **8GB**
Here is the result:

```
siege -c 4000 localhost:8000
```

I got this error:

```
Transactions:                   2164 hits
Availability:                  39.90 %
Elapsed time:                   6.85 secs
Data transferred:               2.52 MB
Response time:                  1.04 secs
Transaction rate:             315.91 trans/sec
Throughput:                     0.37 MB/sec
Concurrency:                  329.74
Successful transactions:        2164
Failed transactions:            3260
Longest transaction:            5.94
Shortest transaction:           0.00
```

And if i use 10k connection:

```
siege -c 10000 localhost:8000
```

I get an error:

```
[error] descriptor table full sock.c:109: Too many open files
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the output from the `ulimit` command.  You'll need to increase the file descriptor limit on both siege and the tornado webserver to finish your benchmark.

Comment: tornado i dont know how, i think it is by default set to max? i'll check siege's one

Comment: Edit: found that it's a linux command, so what is the limit if i've 8 giga ram?

Comment: The default is small, there really isn't a limit... I've set it typically to 32767 which works fine on pretty much anything.

Comment: I assume it's seige that is segmentation faulting - which I'm assuming is a bug in siege with the number of connections.

Comment: which versio you use? because i've downloaded the latest 2.74